# how to make model filed writable using SerializerMethodField

Tags: django-rest-framework

My model is having field- 'packs' as ManyToManyField.

in serializer I have function to get list of packages:

```
packs = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_packs')
def get_packs(self, obj):
    return Packs.objects.filter(rel__id__in=  [obj.id]).order_by("id").values_list("id", flat=True)
```

Now packs is not editable during create/update operation.
How to make it writable. Please suggest?

Comment: here I am just overriding the 'packs' value for increasing db performance. name is same 'packs' in model also in serialize. it is editable before this change.
Please help

Comment: it's not editable because it comes from a callable (a function) which only returns. Also, filter returns a list of objects. You should use .get then. These are only hint's, I don't know how you could do it exactly.

Comment: How to use get in serializer to access mamy2many relation with specified query?

Comment: I didn't think of that. Then you are right, it should be filter. I think that serializer doesn't know what to update, because it gets many fields, that's why it's not editable. Maybe you could then look into a serializer class and see how it handles fields before saving and override it.

Comment: maybe this would help: http://www.jobpedia.in/blog/how-to-index-manytomany-field-in-django/

Comment: thanks but it not useful for me. I am trying to improve performance as using serializer . query is fetching about 50000 manytomany relation which is 'packs'. I just want to show pk of 'packs' so tried with 'SerializerMethodField'. it really boost performance but it makes 'packs' as readonly. I want it writable as it is model field not any extra field.

Comment: you're returning only an id, not a object here, and serializer serializes objects and writes info to objects. probably you should think on how to override your serializer's save method